# Acceptable to Promote Are51 Proposal on Meta?

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable to promote a related Area51 proposal on the meta here?

The proposal is for a sociology/anthropology page

Comment: This always has to be a case by case judgement, so without further specification, I'm afraid we cannot possibly give an appropriate answer here.

Comment: I agree, the answer would be "yes, if appropriate". But I think we can be relatively lenient; this is not the main site.